# Межпроцессное взаимодействие, nodejs + nodejs, nodejs + qt и не только

Tags: qt, node.js, архитектура

Есть необходимость реализовать двухсторонний обмен данными между разными частями системы.
На данный момент в системе присутствуют:

- модуль взаимодействия с внешними пользователями через rest api, реализован на nodejs;
- модуль в котором реализована бизнес логика и взаимодействие с БД, реализован на qt;

Планируется:

- веб морда для удобства взаимодействия с системой физических пользователей, будет написана на reactjs.

Сейчас между nodejs и qt данные гоняют по веб сокетам. По ним же планируем обмен данными и с веб мордой. Еще есть необходимость плагины из которых состоит qt модуль разнести по разным процессам.

Если обмен данными по веб сокетам с фронтендом смущений не вызывает то их использование для организации обмена между qt процессами, а также между ними и nodejs смущает. Есть ли более подходящие технологии для этого с учетом того что qt плагины и nodejs приложения находятся на одном сервере.

Comment: tcp socket, к примеру

Comment: Зачем конкурс? Чем Вас tcp socket не устраивает? Есть и другие виды IPC, конечно, но чем сокет плох?

Comment: @ixSci, я думаю что автор хочет более подробный ответ, чем "посмотрите в сторону этого", и готов дать за это репутацию)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть масса методов взаимодействия между процессами. К примеру, его можно организовать с помощью простого TCP сокета. Для этого есть поддержка в node.js [из коробоки](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html). В Qt для этого используется [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html). Это самый простой вариант, потому что и там и там есть поддержка из коробки и на выходе мы имеем асинхронный IPC.

Другим вариантом может быть использование разделяемой памяти. Судя по всему, есть [горстка дополнений](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=shared%20memory) для node.js добавляющих поддержку оной. В Qt есть готовый класс [QSharedMemory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedmemory.html). Этот метод хуже, т.к. требует дополнительных плагинов и он синхронен(нужно «опрашивать» разделяемую память).

Идём дальше: D-Bus. В node.js есть [дополнение](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbus-native) для этого, в Qt тоже есть: [Qt D-Bus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html).

Безусловно, можно ещё придумать способов. Что из вышеприведённых лучше? Я считаю, что самым простым и удобным будет использование обычного TCP сокета.

Comment: Чем тут плохи udp и local сокеты?

Comment: @sercxjo, зачем тут UDP? Если хочется, то ничем не плох, но я не вижу смысла. И что такое local сокеты?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html

Comment: @sercxjo, ну это чисто Qt-шное понятие и придётся думать как его соединить с node.js.

Comment: Обмен между процессами обычно происходит отдельными пакетами запрос-ответ которые можно прямо отображать на UDP-пакеты.

Comment: @sercxjo, в чём будет преимущество перед TCP, который стандарт де факто для обмена?

Comment: - не нужно придумывать как определить границы запроса/ответа

Comment: @sercxjo, весомо. Про это я не подумал. Обновлю ответ, или Вы свой напишите?

Comment: Про UNIX сокеты для кучи можете дополнить

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, это то о чём говорил sercxjo выше(local сокет). Это не кроссплатформенная штука, которой я не пользовался. Если считаете полезным — напишите свой ответ. Я перечислил далеко не все методы, которые можно использовать для IPC — только самые базовые.

Answer (score 3):

Для организации взаимодействия типа запрос-ответ хорошо подходят пакетно-ориентрованные сокеты типа UDP. В отличие от поточно-ориентрованных, где данные записанные несколькими командами записи могут быть прочитаны за один раз и наоборот, для UDP одной команде записи соответствует одна команда чтения. Таким образом один запрос или ответ упаковываются в один пакет и принимаются одним вызовом `read` или `recv`, в Qt [`readDatagram`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html), в node.js - в обработчике события [`'message'`](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html).

Так как обмен происходит внутри одной машины, за потерю пакетов можно не беспокоиться.

Comment: (> данные записанные несколькими командами записи) Просто отключите nagle алгоритм. Тогда все пакеты будут уходить за 1 команду записи. Считаю, что UDP тут не нужно, так как не гарантирует доставку. При использовании же TCP при падении процесса упадёт коннект, что даст возможность обработать ошибку.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, уходить да, но даже если установлено TCP_NODELAY никто вам не гарантирует, что пакеты будут *приняты* по отдельности. *Внутри одной машины* UDP достаточно надёжен. Если принимающая сторона существует, пакеты не теряются и не перемешиваются. В случае падения принимающего процесса `send` первый раз не вернёт ошибку,  но сразу установится флаг асинхронной ошибки, который можно прочитать через `getsockopt`. Это на C, на сколько это используется в nodejs и qt не знаю.